# How to hide colorscale labels in plotly go?

Tags: python, plotly

I need to hide colorscale labels I am using plotly go, I have code like this

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
z = [1, 3, 5]

x1 = [3, 2, 1]
y1 = [4, 5, 6]
z1 = [2.4, 3, 5]
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    showlegend=False,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        symbol='hexagon2',
        size=12,
        color=z,
        colorscale='rdylbu',
        showscale=True,
        reversescale=True
    )
))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(y=y1,
                          x=x1, showlegend=False,
                          mode='markers', marker=dict(symbol='hexagon2', color=z1,
                                                      colorscale='rdylbu', showscale=True,
                                                      reversescale=True, size=12)))
fig.show()
```

My output looks like this:
[image]

and i need it to be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/reference/) and take the following actions to solve the problem.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
z = [1, 3, 5]

x1 = [3, 2, 1]
y1 = [4, 5, 6]
z1 = [2.4, 3, 5]
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    showlegend=False,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        symbol='hexagon2',
        size=12,
        color=z,
        colorscale='rdylbu',
        showscale=True,
        reversescale=True
    ), marker_colorbar_showticklabels=False,
))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(y=y1,
                          x=x1, showlegend=False,
                          mode='markers', marker=dict(symbol='hexagon2', color=z1,
                                                      colorscale='rdylbu', showscale=True,
                                                      reversescale=True, size=12),
                          marker_colorbar_showticklabels=False,))


fig.show()
```

[image]